# Friction between 2 fluids in Navier Stokes

Tags: fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes

I have a system with 2 different fluids, and I want to write a friction/viscosity term between them in their Navier-Stokes equation. Should it be in the form $M(v_{1}-v_{2})$ with $M$ a friction coefficient or something else ?

Thx in advance

Comment: Are you suggesting that there is slip between the two fluids at their interface?

Comment: I'm in a case where the two fluids are mixed.

Comment: Actually, the form proposed above is better like like $M(c_1 v_1 +c_2 v_2)$ with $c_i$ the concentration of i. What do u think about it ?

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me. What do you mean by " friction/viscosity term *between them*"? N-S equation must be written separately for each fluid (fluid properties appearing in the N-S equation will differ for each fluid), which already includes a viscous term $\mu\nabla^2\mathbf{u}$. Then you must write the appropriate [boundary conditions](http://web2.clarkson.edu/projects/subramanian/ch560/notes/Boundary%20Conditions%20in%20Fluid%20Mechanics.pdf) at the interface between fluids.

Comment: The two fluids are mixed, and there is no clear interface between them. So I assume apart from the viscosity term that you wrote, there is another one for the force that one fluid applies on the other. For example how would you write Navier-Stokes for ink in water ?

Comment: Do you mean that you have a homogeneous solution?

Comment: Right. And my intuition is that if the 2 velocities have the same direction and the velocity of the 2nd species is higher, the time derivative is positive, and else, it is negative, yielding the form (and I'm correcting again) : $Mc_1 c_2 ( v_2 - v_1)$